# Text appearing on hovering image should have different opacity than the image

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have used a wrapper class to put an image and some text together. I want the functionality that the text remains invisible but whenever I hover over the image, the text becomes visible and the image's opacity decreases and the text appearing on the image should have more opacity than the Image.

However, the code which I have written , decreases the opacity of Image on hovering and also makes the opacity of the text equal to that of Image. What should I do in order to ensure that the opacity of text and image remain different ?

```css
/*Portfolio Section*/
html {
    font-size:12px;
}

section{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    height:auto;
    width:90vw;
    margin:auto;
}

#portfolio-header span{
    color:blue;
    font-size:3rem;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:1rem;
    margin-bottom:2rem;
}

.portfolio-images{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.wrapper img{
    width:25rem;
    height:20rem;
    display:inline-block;
}

.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:25rem;
    height:20rem;
    margin-bottom:0.8rem;
}

.img_description{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:white;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity .2s,visibility .2s;
}

.wrapper:hover img{
    background-color:lightgray;
    opacity:0.4;
}

.wrapper:hover .img_description{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/15a25df2f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="portfolio">
            <div id="portfolio-header">
                <span><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                <span>Portfolio</span>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-images">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="Picture1.png" alt="picture"> 
                    <p class="img_description">Write Here Basic Details About The Picture.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="Picture1.png" alt="picture"> 
                    <p class="img_description">Write Here Basic Details About The Picture.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="Picture1.png" alt="picture"> 
                    <p class="img_description">Write Here Basic Details About The Picture.</p>
                </div> 
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="Picture2.png" alt="picture"> 
                    <p class="img_description">Write Here Basic Details About The Picture.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="Picture2.png" alt="picture">
                    <p class="img_description">Write Here Basic Details About The Picture.</p> 
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="Picture2.png" alt="picture"> 
                    <p class="img_description">Write Here Basic Details About The Picture.</p>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code looks right at first glance but you'd need to demonstrate this with **actual** images.

Comment: opacity is rendered last. it wont cancel some other elements opacity. Put you proberly dont want opacity in the first place but a backgroundcolor with transparency for your text -> RGBa

Comment: Your code looks fine. I guess you are looking for some other style. Check https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/poPgMNZ

Comment: *"makes the opacity of the text equal to that of Image"* - The opacity of the text is not equal to the image.

Comment: Your code is fine - but it rather depends on the img whether the white and quite pale blue text shows up well or not (try black and you'll see it has full opacity - and look in your browser devtools to see the opacity that is being picked up).